# AlertDialog "onClick" method not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I currently have an alert dialog that is  being displayed on a fragment. The dialog displays to the user with no issues, but the "***setPositiveButton***" and "***setNegativeButton***" are not responding to the user interaction correctly, the Log.i after the on "***setPositiveButton***" is pressed is the only thing that is actually working. I want it to display a Toast message and travel to a new fragment after the possitive button is has been pressed.

```
    private FragmentRequestCodeBinding binding;

//TAG
private static final String TAG = "requestCodeFragment";

//Values
private String firstLetter = "B";
private int secondLetter = 0;
private String thirdLetter = "0";
private String fourthLetter = "0";
private String fifthLetter = "0";
private String dtcCode = firstLetter + secondLetter + thirdLetter + fourthLetter + fifthLetter;

//Buttons
private Button request;

//Views
View root;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentRequestCodeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    root = binding.getRoot();

    request = root.findViewById(R.id.requestButton);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);


    request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_priority_high_24)
                    .setTitle("Request for " + dtcCode)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to request the following code " +
                            "for this car model?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ticket created successfully!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            navController.navigate(R.id.action_requestCodeFragment_to_navigation_profile);
                            
                            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: Pressed");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Why are you navigating to a destination and then immediately popping it off the back stack? What are you trying to accomplish in your listener?

Comment: O sorry! I forgot to get rid of that before posting. The original code does no have that.

Comment: @JoseOrtega could you please confirm that Toast is not showing when you pressed the **YES** button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother guys, the code is all good. I started using a real device instead of the android emulator and everything is working just fine.